# Drupal: debug in teaserview

Tags: debugging, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-nodes

As soon as i am on a single-view-page, i can use this to see the whole array of my node:

```
dpm($content);
```

it helps me also to get information about the activated fields through "manage display".

but for example on the startpage, there are no singleviews but only lists of teasers and because of that, theres a timeout when trying to debug with dpm($content);

is there someting like

```
dpm($content[5360]);
```

and the number is the nodeid, to get the output of a certain node, but not on a singlepage but on a page with teaserviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have the `dpm($content)`  statement in your node template file?

You should be able to do something like this:

```
if ($node->nid == 5360) {
  dpm($content);
}
```